# So there is any way to use a flutter widget in a iOS or Android app?

Tags: android, swift, flutter, kotlin, dart

Recently at work, I was tasked with finding a way to use a flutter widget inside an iOS and Android app. So I encountered some Docs about it, but I found the android one very inconclusive and the iOS one was even worst. I was hoping you guys could help me.

Some docs and repositories I have seen about the subject already:

- https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app
- https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/main/add_to_app/android_view
- https://medium.com/norsys-octogone/the-power-of-a-flutter-module-in-a-native-app-19285b2b8364

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.